# align vertically text in a navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How I do vertically align text inside a `navbar` or a footer

I tried a couple of things mentioned here but I wasn't able to do it. 
http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Can you at least point me out to a source where I can learn about about alignment

This how it looks:

[image]

Source:

```
  <div class='navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse'>
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
      <div class='container-fluid'>
        <ul class='nav pull-left'>
          <li style='font-size:medium; color: #E8E8E8'>
            <ul class='inline'>
              <li class='active'>
                <i class='icon-warning-sign'></i>
                TEXT HERE
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked!

something magical about the `%a`

```
-# without %a it doesn't go in the middle vertically 
.navbar.navbar-fixed-bottom.navbar-inverse{style: 'position:fixed'}
  .navbar-inner
    %ul.nav.pull-left
      %li.active
        %a
          %span
            %i.icon-warning-sign
            TEXT HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one line of text, set the `line-height` of your containing `nav` to match that of it's `height`, for example:

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
  line-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='navbar'>
  <p>TEXT HERE</p>
</div>
```

[Codepen sketch.](http://cdpn.io/vxywg)

Comment: there should be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Haha, how do you mean? You're the one trying to vertically center a line of text that's nested 8 levels deep.

Comment: If you don't like the code, you could ( and probably should ) rewrite that portion of the code.  Always question code you inherit.

Comment: I inherited this so yes I will

Comment: This is very useful code. I have been at this for hours... I was trying `position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);` and lots of other trickery to no avail... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the best solution, but you can play with the `margin-top` to vertically align stuff.  In your example, just playing around with it in the browser, this got me vertically aligned:

```
      ul.nav li ul li{ margin-top: 10px; }
```

You can adjust it more to your liking by playing with the values or selectors.  Hope it helps.